# Do Workflow Foundation 4 Workflows Preserve Object References After Persistence

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to this question. Is it guaranteed that object references are preserved after persistence?

For example, I have an object with a bunch of properties, and I pass this object around to many different activities which changes the data inside this object. After the workflow is persisted, and revived, is it guaranteed that all activities will have the reference to the same object instance?

Or is it possible that the various activities that have a reference to this object, either via an argument or variable, will end up with a copy?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually asking two different questions here:

**What semantics are used to call activities?**

It is the same as a normal .net function call. Reference types (objects) are passed by reference and value types (bool, int, struct, ...) are passed by value (=copy). So if you inherited your own class `public class MyClass {....}`, it will only pass references around and all your activities work on the very same instance.

**What data gets persisted?**

The complete instance is serialized and persisted. This means all your fields will be there after resuming. Your class have to be serialzable or decorated with a `[DataContract]`attribute. See also this comment: 
[Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 and Persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021433/windows-workflow-foundation-4-0-and-persistence#comment1968339_2041215)

Comment: But my question is, if I pass the same object instance to Activity1.Arg1 and Activity2.Arg2, after persistence, is it guaranteed that object.ReferenceEquals(Activity1.Arg1, Activity2.Arg2)? I would assume this is the case, and from my quick  testing, it seems this is the case, but I'm not sure whether this is coincidence or part of the intended design of WF4.

Comment: If we are talking about reference types, WF4 never makes copies of your instances so ReferenceEquals should always be true except, if your workflow instance gets restored from disk like so: Activity1 => Persist => Restore => Activity2. In this case, ReferenceEquals wont be true, because the restore could happen on another machine, in another appdomain on another day.

Comment: Even if the instance is restored on another machine, another process, another AppDomain, ReferenceEquals should be true right? On restore, only 1 object should be deserialized and assigned to the respective Args or Variables.

Answer (score 1):

Because activities are sequential you are only using one activity at a time.  So once an activity is complete it doesn't matter if it has a reference to the same object as a subsequent activity because the first activity has gone out of scope.

So, yes, you will get the effect of all the activities getting the same referenced object.
Other than when you are using parallel activities the code execution point is inside just one activity so when you persist just one "version" of your object is persisted.  When you come out of persistence that object it restored with its properties and can be passed around between subsequent activities.

I do this by making the object a variable at the top level of my Flowchart activity and handing it out to the Code Ativities inside the Flowchart

Comment: Actually, this makes a lot of sense, since workflows are single-threaded.